# Foundation - The third container is pushed down

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am building a calendar web app that displays a list of events. On larger screen sizes the third event item gets pushed down so that it does not line up with the two events to the left of it. I inspected the CSS of the web app but could not find what was causing this. this also occurs when the screen size is a bit smaller and the events are in a two column layout.

URL: 
http://www.blackduckmn.com/calendar#octoberHash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because you have white space in your container `portfolioContainer october` delete it and it will work fine :
[image]

Comment: Ah I see, I put that in there for compatibility with IE and a add on called swiper.